# Finding A point $Q$ on a surface such that Line $PQ$ get tangent to that surface

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, surfaces, divergence-operator

> Consider the surface $f: x^2 + y^2 - 2z^2 = 1$ and Point $P= (1,1,1)$.
>   We want to find all points $Q$ on the surface such that line $PQ$ get
>   tangent to the surface. Also we want to find the point $Q_0$ with
>   above conditions such that $PQ_0$ gets smallest.

For the first part; I solved the problem like this: $\nabla f = (2x,2y,-4z) , Q=(x,y,z) \Rightarrow PQ : (x-1 , y-1 , z-1)$ and $PQ \perp \nabla f$ by using the dot product we get at last $2x^2 + 2y^2 -4z^2 -2x-2y +4 =0$ and using the equation of surface we get: $x+y-2z =1$ and $x^2 + y^2 -2z^2 = 1$.(Which is a curve - probably and elliptic curve)

After these, I don't know how to find Q such that PQ gets smallest. I know that I must make $(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + (z-1)^2$ smallest but I don't know how to use equations I got to do this.

Comment: @AjayMishra Yes.  The first part of question wants a point Q on the surface such that PQ be tangent to the surface. The second part wants to minimize length of PQ. So yes, The line must be tangent to surface at Q.

Comment: The curve is not elliptic. The points of tangency lie on the polar plane of $P$ and the resulting curve, which is the intersection of a plane and quadric, is a conic.

Comment: @amd , Yes. It was my mistake.

Comment: It should be solvable using Lagrange multipliers, minimizing the square of the distance subject to the two constraints.

Comment: Moreover, one of the constraints is linear, so you can easily solve for, say, $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ and reduce it to a two-dimensional problem with a single constraint.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I think Lagrange multipliers is a good idea. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given point $P=(1,1,1)$, find set $S$ of all $Q=(x,y,z)$ on the surface $x^2+y^2-2z^2=1$ 
subject to the constraint that the line $PQ$ is tangent to the surface at $Q$. Then locate the $Q$ in that set closest to $P$.

OP has already found that the set $S$ satisfies the equations

$$x+y-2z =1 $$
$$x^2 + y^2 -2z^2 = 1 $$

So it remains to minimize

$$ R(x,y,z)=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2 $$
subject to constraints (1) and (2).

Using the method of Lagrange multipliers, let

$$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-2z^2-1 \tag{1}$$

$$g(x,y,z)=x+y-2z-1 \tag{2}$$

Then solve

$$ \begin{cases}
\nabla R(x,y,z)-\lambda\nabla f(x,y,z)-\mu\nabla g(x,y,z)=0&\\
x+y-2z =1&\\
x^2 + y^2 -2z^2 = 1
\end{cases}$$

The gradient equation leads to

$$ x=y=\frac{\mu+2}{2(1-\lambda)} $$

which reduces the other two equations to

$$ \begin{cases}
x=z+\frac{1}{2}&\\x^2=z^2+\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}  $$

giving $x=y=\frac{3}{4},\,z=\frac{1}{4}$. So the nearest $Q$ to $P$ is $Q=\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right)$.